# How can I parse LocalDateTime to java util Date, using a list

Tags: java, parsing

I have this parser:

```
Date.from(data1.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

but I need to parse a list, not single date.

Comment: To be clear: Are you trying to convert a `List<LocalDateTime>` to a `List<Date>` using the aforementioned code?

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, It doesn`t need to be this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java 8's streaming API to apply the same translation to each element of a list:

```
List<LocalDateTime> orig = // something
List<Date> result = 
    orig.stream()
        .map(d -> Date.from(d.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: where i need to put the result list to get this list after parse?

Comment: @dzefrej0 I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I see that you have added two lists, orig and result, result list is not used in this code, and i don`t know how to get access to this result list

Comment: @dzefrej0 The List `result` is produced by the stream. You may need to learn about [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), [aggregate operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html), [`Lambda`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), and the other new “functional” features added to Java.

Comment: @dzefrej0 just use it... This could, e.g., be a value returned from a function. Can you share a fuller snippet of what you're trying to achieve?